# IIOP Protocol Manager failure Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: java, glassfish, corba, iiop

During startup of Glassfish I get the following failure. I do have the `vbjorb.jar` on the domain's classpath where the `org.omg.CORBA.InterfaceDef` resides.

```
SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:305)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IIOP Protocol Manager initialization failed.  Possible cause is that ORB is not available in this container
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeProtocolManager(BaseContainer.java:827)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.<init>(BaseContainer.java:508)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: injection failed on class org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POAProtocolMgr from org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl@1545b48
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager$1.run(InjectionManager.java:259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/InterfaceDef
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:170)
```